# how to mongoid projects <=has_many=> users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I just began using Mongoid last week. I am running into this association problem which I am unsure if my approach is correct. So i thought I would ask for some opinion

I have a User model and a Project model
    class User
        include Mongoid::Document
        field :email
    end
    class Project
        include Mongoid::Document
        field :name
    end

Actually the user model is created by Devise, an authentication gem, so I guess it cannot be embedded in Project.

So if I wanted the old many to many associations where a user can have many projects and a project can have many users. how should I set this up?

My approach is this:
    class User
        include Mongoid::Document
        field :email
        references_many :projects
        referenced_in    :project, :inverse_of => :users
    end
    class Project
        include Mongoid::Document
        field :name
        references_many :users
        referenced_in    :user, :inverse_of => :projects
    end

Is this the correct way with respect to MongoDB architecture to do such a many-to-many association?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

document databases are actually pretty terrible when it comes to many-to-many, since that is pretty much the essence of relational data. mongo shines when the data is hierarchical rather then relational.

What I would do (assuming there will be more to users then just their email), is store the users in a seperate collection, and store arrays of user ids in your project documents. If it is just emails, I would store them inside the project documents, and just accept that it will be more expensive then it probably should be for users to change their email.

Comment: Hey Matt, thanks for your input. It's valuable in that it confirms 1) I am not crazy to suspect there is genuinely no good way yet to do many2many assoc. --- I just, just dug up a slide by Kyle Banker here http://www.slideshare.net/kbanker/mongodb-the-way-and-its-power on the 52nd slide, he demo how to do a m-2-m product-category assoc by storing category objectIds in product.in pseudo language if one is to find all products in a category: Product.find category_id = 123. but to find all categories in a product, you have to start from category class:Category.find(id in product.category.ids.

Comment: @Nik: Honestly, I am probably only about a month and a half passed where you now, and only had an answer so quick because it wasn't that long ago I was looking for the same info ;-) I would highly recommend watching this http://vimeo.com/9864311, helped me a lot.

Comment: thanks for the link and your experience. -- at least makes me feel better that I'm not alone in this, to say the least.

Answer (score 5):

The Mongoid documentation explains how to do this at http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#has_and_belongs_to_many . Scroll down to the heading *Relational Associations*. In the code example that's shown, there's a many-to-many relationship between the Person and Preference models.